# How to get packages on Ubuntu machine from local artifactory server

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory

**what is the issue**

i have setup the local artifactory server to download all the debian/ubuntu packages.

here are my remote repos :

```
repo key : op.archive.ubuntu.com , URL : http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
repo key : op.security.ubuntu.com, url : http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

and this mapped to virtual repo :

```
https://<<url>>/artifactory/op-deb-debian-virtual
```

now, in the ubuntu machine, here are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb https://<<url>>/artifactory/op-deb-debian-virtual/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb https://<<url>>/artifactory/op-deb-debian-virtual/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

but now, when i am running `apt-get update` command, it is failing with the following error. not able to understand , is the issue with artifactory server , sources.list OR something else

**what is the error**

> Err:5 https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/main
>   amd64 Packages   401  Unauthorized Ign:6
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/main i386
>   Packages Ign:7 https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch/main all Packages Ign:8
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/main
>   Translation-en_US Ign:9
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/main
>   Translation-en Ign:10
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/contrib
>   amd64 Packages Ign:11
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/contrib
>   i386 Packages Ign:12
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/contrib all
>   Packages Ign:13 https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch/contrib Translation-en_US Ign:14
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/contrib
>   Translation-en Ign:15
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch/non-free
>   amd64 Packages Err:20
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages   401  Unauthorized Ign:21
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/main i386 Packages Ign:22
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/main all Packages Ign:23
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/main Translation-en_US Ign:24
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/main Translation-en Ign:25
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/contrib amd64 Packages Ign:26
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/contrib i386 Packages Ign:27
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/contrib all Packages Ign:28
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/contrib Translation-en_US Ign:29
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/contrib Translation-en Ign:30
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch-updates/non-free amd64 Packages Reading package lists... Done
>   W: The repository 'https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual
>   stretch Release' does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a
>   repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially
>   dangerous to use. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation
>   and user configuration details. W: The repository
>   'https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual stretch-updates
>   Release' does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository
>   can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details. E: Failed to fetch
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   401  Unauthorized E: Failed to fetch
>   https://<>/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   401  Unauthorized E: Some index files failed to download. They have
>   been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**what is expected**

after adding proper artifactory  url in the sources.list, should work. thats what i did , still not working

please suggest

**update 1**

the previous issue resolved. it was due to the permission issue. i used username and password (base 64 format) and it worked . but now the issues is with 403 forbidden

**exact error**

```
E: Failed to fetch https://artifactory-na.honeywell.com/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch https://artifactory-na.honeywell.com/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch https://artifactory-na.honeywell.com/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch https://artifactory-na.honeywell.com/artifactory/op2-deb-debian-virtual/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

for me the line ,

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

is triggering.
is it something like , some mirror is down ?? how can i fix this ... ?
even if mirror is down, i feel that mirror or apt-get should take care that ??

please suggest

Comment: Can you please reformat the error messages to be more legible?  Try indenting with 4 spaces so that line breaks are preserved.

Comment: done. please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause for a 403 in this scenario is that the user used in the sources.list does not have 'Deploy' permissions on the Remote repositories (op.archive.ubuntu.com and op.security.ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a `403 (Forbidden)` response because I was running as `root`. Perhaps the user name is passed to the server, and then the server requires a password if it's `root`.